# MySQL: LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, python, mysql

I try to import data from a txt file into a table in my database I created.
I use this command to import data from a python script:

```
query = """LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/Mesures.txt' INTO TABLE mesure FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (Temperature, Humidite, Pression, Altitude);"""
```

Unfortunately nothing is imported into my table. So I test this command by connecting directly to my database with this command **mysql -u root -p**  in the terminal.
And as magic the data have been imported into my table. I can see the contents of my table.

If you have an idea why the import is not carried with my script I am taker.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know python but do you really need the triple quotation marks around a string? Would single quotation be sufficient?

Comment: You should probably use a raw string so that `\n` will be sent literally to MySQL.